# in Snowflake, Does resize an existing warehouse helps in improving the performance of a running query?

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, warehouse

in Snowflake, Does resize of an existing warehouse helps in improving the performance of a running query ?

Answer (score 1):

Resizing a running warehouse does not impact queries that are already being processed by the warehouse; the additional servers are only used for queued and new queries.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#scaling-up-vs-scaling-out

Answer (score 0):

If your warehouse was severely undersized for the running query, you would be better off aborting that query, and rerunning it after the warehouse has been resized appropriately.